# How can I reset the route in a navigator by clicking the button in the navigator a second time in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This sounds confusing reading it but I don't know how to formulate it better, but let me elaborte: I have a bottom navigator with, let's say, three different children: Home, music and books. When I click on the book page, and move up the route to, for example the music page shows a list of songs, click on that and move to one song and then click on that song's author to go to this page. Now, I decided that if I want to click the Home page to go there, and click the music page again, I will then land back on the author's page. That is just a design choice. If I then want to go back to the music list page, I will have to spam the back button in order to go there again, but I want to be able to do this by clicking the music navigator button again.[image]

Quickly summarized: Leaving a page in a navigator should keep the route, but be reset by clicking the page in the Navigator again

Edit: I added a picture on how i want this to work. (I forgot to add the small back arrows after song a, but they don't mean anything anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the easier part,
if you want the user to go back to let's say music screen after he **spams** the button you can check in the `onTap` method of the bottom navigation bar if the clicked index is the same as the current index then use the navigator's `popUntil` method

```
 bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.music_note),
          title: Text('Music'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.school),
          title: Text('School'),
        ),
      ],
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
      onTap: (index) {
        if(_selectedIndex == index && index == 1){
         Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName("/Home"));
        } else if(_selectedIndex == index && index == 2){
         Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName("/Music"));
        }
        //etc...
        setState((){
         _selectedIndex = index;
        });
      },
    ),
```

I know it doesn't look elegant and it might be cumbersome if you have more than 3 views, but that's all I can think of right now.

As for navigating in the same view (Music for instance) and keeping the navigator state when switched to another view (Home for example); I'd advise using this awesome package by Orfali Ayham :

https://pub.dev/packages/custom_navigator

or implement your own custom navigator following this article written by the awesome Hans Muller :

https://medium.com/flutter/getting-to-the-bottom-of-navigation-in-flutter-b3e440b9386

Comment: i don't know if i completly understand your approach, but are you saying that i count how many the same page has been clicked, and at the first click i go back to the last page, and at another click i reset the route to the new page?

Comment: Sorry if my code isn't clear, I omitted some bits as they weren't relevant imo,
The approach is, mostly if the user navigates he doesn't click on the same bottom navigation item, if he is in Home he will click on Music to navigate there and that's fine, that will only `setState` of the _selectedIndex value but if he clicks on the same index again (he is on Music and clicks Music again) then we will use navigator to pop until the root screen of that destination.
I hope that clarifies my intent.

Answer (score 1):

i think you want remove previous page after you go to next page

if you want remove previous page you should use pushReplacement instead of push, like this

```
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return PageOne();
          },
        ));
```

Comment: I don't think this would do quite what i envisioned, so i drew what i immagined with paint and added it to my post. The first time i click on the icon in the navigator i want to go to the last route on this navigator page, the second time i click it i want to reset it back

Comment: i think you should use pushAndRemoveUntil in step 4 , for going to home page